# Kotlin convert csv to map <String, List>

Tags: kotlin

I have following CSV

```
US;Americas
CA;Americas
FR;Europe
CH;Asia
...
```

I want to have Map of -> String, List, is it possible to achieve this via associate, or something else ?

So far I have this:

```
csv.split("\n").associate { 
  val (code, region) = it.split(";") 
  region to code 
}
```

but this is just mapping the region to only one code, also tried

```
region to listOf(code)
```

expected result:

```
Americas -> US, CA, BR ...
Europe -> FR, IT, CH ...
Asia -> CH, JP, KR ...
```

Comment: Be careful with solutions that "simply" split by `;`.  If the country name has a `;` escaped, the simple solution will cut the field with the `;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`associate` would replace the value if the key already iterated.
You can instead use `groupBy` to specify key and value for the map

```
csv.split("\n").map {
    val (code, region) = it.split(";")
    region to code
}.groupBy({ it.first }) { it.second }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
csv
  .split("\n")
  .groupBy({ it.substringAfter(";") }) { it.substringBefore(";") }})
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to sidgate's excellent answer you could also do

```
csv.split("\n").groupBy({
    it.split(";")[1]
}){
    it.split(";")[0]
}
```

It avoids having to create a map first, but calls split more often. I'm not sure what would be better in terms of speed/efficiency.